# Tagging top 10 friends in photo with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, tagging

I want totag more than one friend.
I want to tag about 10 friends top 10
if any body knows ?
New Here thats why.
Here is code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
'$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

$coded = $_REQUEST['code'];

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$name = "".$user_profile['name']."";
$fbid = "".$user_profile['id']."";


$fql = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1='.$fbid.'+ORDER+BY+rand()+LIMIT+1&access_token='.$access_token.'';
 $fqlresult = file_get_contents($fql); 
   $f = json_decode($fqlresult, true);

 $friends = $f['data']['0']['uid2'];

 $fql2 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$friends.'';
  $fqlresult2 = file_get_contents($fql2); 
 $f2 = json_decode($fqlresult2, true);

 $friend = $f2['name'];  



 $file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file
 $data = array(array('tag_uid' => $friends, 'x' => rand() % 100, 'y' => rand() % 100 ));
 $data = json_encode($data);
//, 'tags' => $data,
```

Comment: Its Only Tagging One friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great example of how to tag a person in a photo:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/

Here's how to get 10 friends via FQL:
`SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 10`

Here's how to do it with the Graph API:
`/me/friends?limit=10&fields=id`

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()+LIMIT+1&access_token='.$access_token.'                   Changed Still Not Working

Comment: Still Not getting please will you explain little... ?

Comment: Hey DMCS Can You Help Me With AN Issue

Comment: Post a link to your new question below.  I will go the link and see if I can help you out :)  Happy Coding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771124/upload-photo-offline-access   Help Me Here. How To Upload Photo To user's wall from offline access token ?